# Call my function

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a function in VBA and I have no idea how to call this.

```
Public Function FindTwoStrings(rng As Range, s1 As String, _
  s2 As String) As Integer
    'Application.Volatile
    If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then Exit Function
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim accumulator As Integer
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If (InStr(1, UCase(cell.Value), UCase(s1), _
          vbTextCompare) > 0) Or (InStr(1, UCase(cell.Value), _
          UCase(s2), vbTextCompare) > 0) Then _
          accumulator = Me.Cells(cell.Row, 5) + accumulator
    Next cell
End Function
```

How can I call this function in my cell? I have tried to do `=Find....` but it cannot find my function. Is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: where is this located in your workbook?

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `FindTwoStrings`?

Comment: in the code section of my workbook on Sheet 1

Comment: and in my cell I wanna call it in order to provide the parameters

Comment: Paste this line `FindTwoStrings = accumulator` just before `End Function` and move the entire code to a module.

Comment: Siddharth, I want to give you the right answer but you posted a comment. But Brad gave an explanation as to why? Who do you think should get the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put user defined function in `Modules`. Not in `Classes` or in objects like forms, worksheets, or `Thisworkbook`.

And you need to set a return value for your function before it exits otherwise it will always have the default value of `0`.

You might need to rethink your line

```
accumulator = Me.Cells(cell.Row, 5) + accumulator
```

<strike>because you cannot access anything other than what was passed into a UDF. So references to `Me` will not be allowed.</strike>

**Edit:**
You cannot access objects using the `Me` keyword in a module (where a UDF is required to reside) because `Me` refers to the non-static object in which the code resides, but modules are static this `Me` is illogical. As Chris points out in the comments you are allowed to *access* objects that were not passed in but instead of doing so through the `Me` keyword you need to reference them explicitly such as `ThisWoorkBook.Sheets("sheetname").Cells(cell.row,5)`

Comment: Your explanation of why `Me` is a problem isn't quite right.  A `UDF` can _access_  pretty much anything, it just can't _change_ anything.  The issue is that in a `Module`, `Me` has no meaning and doesn't exist.

Comment: @chrisneilsen You're right about the modifying state issue. So yes, if the OP wants to refer to those cells he'll need to do so explicitly through `Sheets("SheetName").Cells(Cell.row,5)`. Modules are static and `Me` is only relevant to non-static objects. I'll change what I wrote

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

1. An Excel custom function (the kind you're trying to create where it shows up as an available keyword in the cell's formula) can only change the value of one cell. You'll note that all of the built-in Excel functions (e.g., =LEFT) only affect the value of the cell that they're used in.
2. The method signature that Excel is looking for is a range... I don't know if it will accept multiple parameters as in your example.
3. It doesn't look like you are setting the value of FindTwoStrings anywhere. That's how the method knows what value to return.

Following is an example of a little function I wrote to concatenate a range into a single string delimited by commas. You call it with =cvsRange( [ some range ])

```
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)
    Dim csvRangeOutput As String
    For Each entry In myRange
      If Len(entry) > 0 Then
        csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & entry.Value & ","
      End If
    Next
    If Len(csvRangeOutput) > 2 Then
         csvRange = Mid(csvRangeOutput, 1, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1)
     Else
         csvRange = ""

      End If

End Function
```

HTH...